# How to determine which rows were selected while in editing mode

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I have multiple selection during editing selected for my uitableviewcontroller.  What I'm doing is enabled an action button when in editing mode so they can select a group of items and assign them.  I have the following method tied to the action button.

```
- (void)assignSelected
{

    for(int i = 0; i < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++)
    {

    }
}
```

What I'm not sure is how to determine if the row is selected in my for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have an array of selected rows. When a row is selected then add that row to the array. Then, you can loop through that array in your for loop.